# How to improve SQL read performance using EF core

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

Every now and then a query throws time out exception. The SqlCommand.TimeOut is set to default 30 seconds.

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution timeout
> expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
> operation or the server is not responding.
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): The wait operation timed
> out.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__169_0(Task`1 result)      at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task&
> currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)        at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
> ClientConnectionId:2daf9373-898b-481d-a7ef-8688c1e1efed  Error
> Number:-2,State:0,Class:11

As per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) SqlCommandTimeout is

> This property is the cumulative time-out (for all network packets that
> are read during the invocation of a method) for all network reads
> during command execution or processing of the results. A time-out can
> still occur after the first row is returned, and does not include user
> processing time, only network read time.
>
> For example, with a 30 second time out, if Read requires two network
> packets, then it has 30 seconds to read both network packets. If you
> call Read again, it will have another 30 seconds to read any data that
> it requires.

I have already verified the indexes multiple times. The `order` table do have records in millions (6M+). The code that receives this exception looks like this.

```
    public async Task<Order> GetByID(int orderID)
    {
        var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var wo = await _dbContext.Orders
            .Where(x => x.OrderID == orderID)                
            .Select(x => new WorkOrder()
            {
                OrderID = x.OrderID,
                ItemID = x.ItemID,
                ItemName = x.ItemName,
                OrderStatusID = x.OrderStatusID,
                OrderStatus = x.OrderStatus,
                Template = new Template()
                {
                    TemplateModel = x.Template.TemplateModel
                },
                Responses = x.Responses.Select(r => new Response()
                {
                    ResponseID = r.ResponseID,
                    ResponseStatusID = r.ResponseStatusID,
                    ResponseStatus = r.ResponseStatus,
                    //some more property assignments
                }).ToList()
            })
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        var end = DateTime.UtcNow;
        
        _logger.LogInformation($"EF-{end.Substract(start}");

        return wo;
    }
```

Here are the two logs for a single execution. *(Note this is not a instance where it throws time out exception.)*

EF Log

```
Executed DbCommand ("1"ms) [Parameters=["@__orderID_0='?' (DbType = Int32)"], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']"  ""SELECT [t].[OrderID],
```

My custom log shows total time

```
EF-00:00:00.2109107
```

In this particular instance it take only 1 ms to execute SQL and 21 ms for complete EF call. So from the logs I noticed the actual time to execute the SQL is very less and it takes longer to read the result and construct the result set.

**Questions**

1. What are the other things I can check and try? (Web Server and SQL Server are two different EC2 servers)
2. Is there a way to improve SQL read and result set building performance?
3. Can EF generate query with READONLY clause?

**UPDATE 1**
I have also tried EF Core's `.AsSplitQuery()` options with no or lower performance. This loads collection is separate db query.

Comment: Could be a number of things. Is there blocking on the server due to something such as a slow update on those tables or database maintenance process? What about network stability?  Also is there a way to output the raw SQL generated by the entity-framework? Kind of hard to optimize a query without the raw SQL being executed

Comment: 1) try to use `FirstOrDefaultAsync`, `SingleOrDefaultAsync` may cause full table scan. 2) try to add `AsSplitQuery`

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` vs. `SingleOrDefault` methods generally generate identical SQL except Single flavours will select the top 2 rows. The difference is that EF will inspect the # of rows returned and catch situations where more than one result was passed back. First flavour methods will just return whichever TOP 1 comes back.

Comment: Try setting Responses in separate statement. Otherwise try Include function on Responses.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check would be to capture the exact SQL being sent to the server. My guess is that the queries you are having issues with will be getting back Lists of results.  Run that query with a profiler and look at the time taken, # of DB Reads, etc. Look at the execution plan and look at index utilization. Developing with an ORM efficiently is a bit different to traditional data access via views and stored procedures. Typically you will want to build your Linq queries and projections and run them against a database to inspect things like index utilization while considering real-world-like usage patterns to prioritize where the best "bang" you can get from indexing, and identifying heavier operations like reports where you might want to employ something like a queuing mechanism to prevent too many expensive queries that "touch" a lot of data from being kicked off all at once triggering lock delays and deadlocks.

The solution to your particular problem will most likely be revealed by looking at the query(ies) being run.

Some general things to consider and look into around query performance:

When working with EF and projection to view models / DTOs, the first step is to get the view models down to the bare minimum data needed. If you can expand a selection from that result, consider an async Ajax call to load that one expansion on demand. Warning signs I look out for is when loading collections of data seeing those items returned containing child collections of data. For something like search results etc. this is something that should be avoided at all costs. Users *might* inspect a few of those related collections, but that is a huge overhead for something that might never be seen.

Always ensure that results are paginated if there is ever a possibility of more than a reasonable screen full of data (I.e. 25-100 rows) can be returned. Many times I see tests in development where the sample set is tiny, only to find that once the system is set loose in production it grinds to a halt because users have the ability to return 25% of the entire data source via a search. Also employ measures in all search criteria to ensure searches aren't kicked off with useless criteria. (I.e. minimum lengths on search strings)